# text going out of div when generating with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am showing notifications to user with ajax call in dropdown, everything works fine but my text is going out of div, I tried `word-wrap:break-word` but it is not working.

I tried many ways to resolve it but unable to find the solution, here is my code.

Here I can't use ajax, so I predefined the values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      function notification_li(el) {
        return '<a style="display:inline-flex;" href='+el.absolute_url+' class="dropdown-item notify-item">'
                +'<img style="max-height:40px;margin-right:15px;" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src='+el.by_img+'>'
                +'<div style="width:70%; word-wrap:break-word;"><p style="word-wrap:break-word;">'+toTitleCase(el.by)+': '+toTitleCase(el.verb)+'- |'
                +toTitleCase(el.title)+' |'
                +'</p></div>'
                +'<img style="max-height:45px;" class="img-fluid float-right" src='+el.img+'>'
                +'</a>'
      }
      function toTitleCase(str) {
        return str.replace(/(?:^|\s)\w/g, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
      });
      }

  $('#notification-drop').unbind().on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {

    var dropMenu = $('#dropdownnotifyButton');
    $('#ajax-notifications-container').empty()

 el = {'title':'This is a long title for test adoijadhaiojdkoahdiuadjhiaudoadiuahdioajkadjkj',
    'absolute_url':'www.google.com',
    'by_img':'https://smalltotall.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/google-favicon-vector-400x400.png',
    'by':'Google','verb':'Check out my new developed website',
    'img':'https://smalltotall.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/google-favicon-vector-400x400.png'}
    $('#ajax-notifications-container').append(notification_li(el))
});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group" id="notification-drop">
  <span type="button" class="notification-bell" data-url="{% url 'communications:get_notifications' %}" data-target="dropdownnotifyButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'icons/baseline-notifications-24px.svg' %}" alt="">
    <span>2 notifications</span>
  </span>
  <div style="max-width: 520px;" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownnotifyMenu" id="dropdownnotifyButton">
    <h5 class="dropdown-header" style="text-transform:uppercase;">notifications</h5>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <div id="ajax-notifications-container" style="word-break: break-all;width: 520px;">

    </div>
    <div id="waitnotiload" style="display:block; text-align:center; padding: 50px;">
      <img style="height:50px;" class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'loading/Rolling-1s-200px.gif' %}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that the notification container have `max-width with 520px` and the text should be in 70% area, if long the automatically break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added one more css property : "white-space: normal" to `<p>` tag in your below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      function notification_li(el) {
        return '<a style="display:inline-flex;" href='+el.absolute_url+' class="dropdown-item notify-item">'
                +'<img style="max-height:40px;margin-right:15px;" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src='+el.by_img+'>'
                +'<div style="width:70%; word-wrap:break-word;"><p style="white-space: normal;word-wrap:break-word;">'+toTitleCase(el.by)+': '+toTitleCase(el.verb)+'- |'
                +toTitleCase(el.title)+' |'
                +'</p></div>'
                 +'</a>'
      }
      function toTitleCase(str) {
        return str.replace(/(?:^|\s)\w/g, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
      });
      }

  $('#notification-drop').unbind().on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {

    var dropMenu = $('#dropdownnotifyButton');
    $('#ajax-notifications-container').empty()

 el = {'title':'This is a long title for test adoijadhaiojdkoahdiuadjhiaudoadiuahdioajkadjkj',
    'absolute_url':'www.google.com',
    'by_img':'https://smalltotall.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/google-favicon-vector-400x400.png',
    'by':'Google','verb':'Check out my new developed website',
    'img':'https://smalltotall.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/google-favicon-vector-400x400.png'}
    $('#ajax-notifications-container').append(notification_li(el))
});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group" id="notification-drop">
  <span type="button" class="notification-bell" data-url="{% url 'communications:get_notifications' %}" data-target="dropdownnotifyButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'icons/baseline-notifications-24px.svg' %}" alt="">
    <span>2 notifications</span>
  </span>
  <div style="max-width: 520px;" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownnotifyMenu" id="dropdownnotifyButton">
    <h5 class="dropdown-header" style="text-transform:uppercase;">notifications</h5>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <div id="ajax-notifications-container">

    </div>
    <div id="waitnotiload" style="display:block; text-align:center; padding: 50px;">
      <img style="height:50px;" class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'loading/Rolling-1s-200px.gif' %}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PankajSharma Welcome Pankaj!

Answer (score 1):

Conflict CSS Bootstrap Class .dropdown-item

Add this CSS

```
#ajax-notifications-container .dropdown-item{
white-space: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The div styling is overridden by some CSS, try normalizing the `white-space`.

```
white-space: normal;
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, here is the problem  in `dropdown-item` property...thank you